# Перебор соседних элементов по "кругу"

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, события

Страничка заполняется квадратами, размер которых задается с помощью `prompt`. Ширина и высота окна формируется в соответствии от размера самого окна.

Хочу сделать что бы при клике на один из квадратов, все квадраты вокруг него изменяли цвет и так по степени нарастания области (как волна после того как кинул предмет в воду).

Но не хватает опыта, помогите придумать саму логику. Думал по индексам писать формулу, но тогда формула нужна для каждого квадрата.

Comment: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/falkone/73gLc3ap/1/)

Comment: Я бы начал с того, что стал бы хранить координаты в двухмерном массиве

Comment: Согласен с Вами, сейчас пробую этот метод

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот пример реализации:

[Песочница](http://jsfiddle.net/LbISS/440amm96/11/)

Код достаточно неаккуратный, так что не надо воспринимать его как готовый и использовать прямо в таком виде.

Основные моменты:
1) Нам по клику нужно запустить рекурсию - делаем соответствующую рекурсивную функцию - `function propagate(item)`
2) Распространение рекурсии по  соседним клеткам - делаем функцию получения соседних клеток `function getAdjacent(item)`
3) Защита от бесконечного цикла - для примера я просто впихнул глобальный массив id клеток `visitedItems`

А дальше нужно приводить в корректный вид, править граничные условия и приводить условие распространение к нужному виду, обрабатывать/запрещать несколько кликов и пр.

Comment: Весьма интересная реализация, сделал по другому, но у Вас достаточно хороший вариант реализации.

Comment: Игрался с вашей песочницей минут 10)) Спасибо!! Вы там заметили, что можно посылать волны навстречу друг другу??? мышкой только успевай щелкать